# Where could I find biology-specialized transcription services for my conference?

Tags: terminology, hearing

I'm a conference organizer for various conferences in the field of biology. Just recently, I stumbled upon this Nature article: https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-03487-2 and I have difficulties in finding biology-specific expert transcription services for my conferences. The generally well-known transcription service providers do not have people available that are familiar with the ubiquitous scientific terminology used by speakers on my conferences. Where could I find scientific experts that are capable of transcribing terminology-heavy talks across various fields of biology and willing to do so?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about a problem in biology.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**
To provide accessible conferences for the hearing impaired, automated artificial intelligence (AI) based captioning services are a good and affordable substitute to live captioners these days.

**Background**
I took the liberty to outsource this question to a giant in the field I work in (Auditory Neuroscience and specifically auditory prosthetics) and they wrote me the following back, and I quote (web links and comments in square brackets added by me):

> *'We previously used a remote live transcription service that cost
> about $5000* [USD] *for the* [conference] *week.  But the AI based automatic transcription
> service is now so good we didn’t think there was enough difference in
> quality to justify the expense of live captioners.  The institutional
> version of [**Zoom has AI captioning**](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/207279736-Managing-closed-captioning-and-live-transcription) built in – there’s a cc button at
> the bottom of the screen, and the [**captioning built in to youtube**](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2734796?hl=en) is
> excellent for prerecorded videos.  We used these two for the recent*
> [conference].'